# How to change file_roots and pillar_roots in salt command without updating the configuration file

Tags: salt-stack

All of our salt scripts are located in `/srv/salt/` and `/srv/pillar/` directories and they are synced with SVN.

In salt configuration file (`/etc/salt/master`) I have defined the `file_roots` and `pillar_roots` as below so once any salt command is executed, it uses these paths.

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/

pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/pillar/
```

I want to create a new directory and duplicate all the scripts there (`/srv/salt_test/salt/` and `/srv/salt_test/pillar/`) for test.

Is there any way that I can pass parameters to salt command to force it to use these test path? Something like:

```
$salt file_roots=/srv/salt_test/salt/  pillar_roots=/srv/salt_test/pillar/ servername.domain.com state.sls weblogic.install
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution and would like to share it here:

I've updated `/etc/salt/master` as below:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/
  test:
    - /srv/salt_test/

pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/pillar/
  test:
    - /srv/pillar_test/
```

Then restarted salt on master and minions. Now I can use `saltEnv=test pillarEnv=test` options to force salt master to read scripts from `/srv/pillar_test/` and `/srv/salt_test/`

Sample:

```
$salt minion.domain.com state.sls weblogic.install saltEnv=test pillarEnv=test
```

Hope it will be useful for someone else.